# mongoose queries execution order

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm having a problem in My code using nodejs and mongoose. where I have a function that is supposed to get books from mongodb ( book.findOne) then update them using second query (updateMany). 
the problem is that UpdateMany query executes before getting the books ..so my array stays empty and nothing is updated.
I know that node.js is asynchronous but how could i solve this ?

```
function UpdateBulk(completeValidBooks){
    var existingRowsInDb = [];
    completeValidBooks.forEach(function(currentBook) {

           book.findOne({'ISIN':  currentBook.ISIN }, 
            function(error, result) {
              existingRowsInDb.push(result);             
            });
          });


        book.updateMany(existingRowsInDb, (err,docs) => {
          err ? console.log(err) : console.log(`updated ${docs.length}`);

          });



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using promise you can do something like this:

```
function UpdateBulk(completeValidBooks) {
  GetExistingRows(completeValidBooks).then((existingRowsInDb) => {
    book.updateMany(existingRowsInDb, (err, docs) => {
      err ? console.log(err) : console.log(`updated ${docs.length}`);
    });
  })
}

function GetExistingRows(completeValidBooks) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var existingRowsInDb = [];
    completeValidBooks.forEach((currentBook) => {
      book.findOne({
        'ISIN': currentBook.ISIN
      }, (error, result) => {
        existingRowsInDb.push(result);
      });
    });
    resolve(existingRowsInDb);
  })
}
```

Using callback you can do like this:

```
function UpdateBulk(completeValidBooks) {
  GetExistingRows(completeValidBooks, (existingRowsInDb) => {
    book.updateMany(existingRowsInDb, (err, docs) => {
      err ? console.log(err) : console.log(`updated ${docs.length}`);
    });
  })
}

function GetExistingRows(completeValidBooks, callback) {
  var existingRowsInDb = [];
  completeValidBooks.forEach((currentBook) => {
    book.findOne({
      'ISIN': currentBook.ISIN
    }, (error, result) => {
      existingRowsInDb.push(result);
    });
  });
  callback(existingRowsInDb);
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot will give it a try , but is there a solution without using promises ? maybe with just callbacks ?

Comment: Updated answer, have a look, let me know if there is any concern.

Comment: im gonna try it and give u a feedback as soon as possible.

Comment: The two solutions u provided didn't work ,they end up with the same result as the original problem . finally i got it to work using asynch and await . thx for ur effort. gonna post the solution later